# Serialization and hashing

Tags: c#, sql, database, security, hash

I was trying to think about data integrity. I have an object that I'm going to serialize into the db. Once it's serialized I was going to take a hash of it and store it with the data as a separate column in the DB.

Then when I get the data from the db I could check the hash and then deserialize the data if the hashes match.

Is there a point to that or am I just wasting CPU? Are there other methods of storing a serialized object and then verifying that the data was not tampered with in the database. The program storing the data may not be the same as the program reading the data.

My specific example is creating an EmailMessage object (since System.Net.Mail.MailMessage cannot be serialized), serializing it and creating the hash. Both are stored in the database. Later I can take the serialized EmailMessage and the hash. I retrieve the EmailMessage and create another hash. If the original hash is the same as the new hash then populate a MailMessage object and send it. Otherwise, create a TamperedWithException().

The code below is what I am using to make the hash. I am using json.net to do the serializing.

```
public static class MD5HashHelper
{
    public static string CreateHash(string str)
    {
        string hash;
        using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
        {
            hash = BitConverter.ToString(
              md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))
            ).Replace("-", String.Empty);
        }
        return hash;
    }
    public static bool CompareWithHash(this string str, string hash)
    {
        string strHash = CreateHash(str);

        return strHash.Equals(hash,StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

This particular table is not encrypted yet. An attacker could make a change and create another hash. This is part of why I think there are probably better ways to do this.

Below is the serialization:

```
public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        return json;
    }

    public static T JSONToObject<T>(this string json)
    {
        Object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I agree that it seems reasonable ... but also I'd ask 1) what your hashing algorithm will be (i.e., why assume that an attacker can't just re-hash the data), 2) whether you're encrypting your database, 3) whether there aren't places within your application environment that are more high-value than your database, in terms of attack vectors.

Comment: Added a couple code samples for hashing and serializing. In terms of attack vectors, this is outgoing communications and does not affect incoming application data.

Comment: I would, at least, add something into the code to avoid the hash to be directly the md5 of the message. At the moment I can think just of some fixed "salt" to add in the code before creating the hash, but I hope someone will come with better ideas (edit: in this case all the programs accessing the info should have a shared Salt,  that makes it even more undesiderable)

Comment: By the way,  which database are we talking about?

Comment: What is your threat model, that is who are you defending against and what kind of attack? If you don't define the threat model you can not create meaningful security.

Comment: @Insac SQL Server 2012

Comment: @zaph This is a new portion of an application and I'm just trying to do a little due diligence in security hardening. This could be from actual attacks or flubs by database/web programmers.

Comment: Then don't even bother with the hash. My attack: read the data, make my changes, create a new hash, save the modified data and hash back to the DB. There are solutions to such an attack but you have to define the value of what you are protecting and from whom. Hashes generally work for data when they are not both available together. An example, Apple provides their updates on one channel and emails the hashes to their security email list, a seperate channel.

Comment: @zaph This is the precise thought of why I'm curious if it is worth anything to use. Insac mentioned the salt which is an extension of what I'm currently doing. I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: A salt could help as long as it is kept secret. But that is a problem because it also has to be available to the legitimate signer and thus will probably be available to an attacker. Again, what attack and what attacker. Trying to be secure from all attackers is generally not possible without severe access restrictions and hardware such as HSMs. Even then there are nations states with huge budgets and in the end [Rubber-hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis).

Comment: @zaph I meant that I would accept your answer about not bothering with the hash unless I had the hash separate from the data and needing to define the attacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A salt could help as long as it is kept secret. But that is a problem because it also has to be available to the legitimate signer and thus will probably be available to an attacker. Is the hash salt is not don't even bother with the hash. My attack: read the data, make my changes, create a new hash, save the modified data and hash back to the DB.

There are solutions to such an attack but you have to define the value of what you are protecting and from whom. Hashes generally work for data when they are not both available together. An example, Apple provides their updates on one channel and emails the hashes to their security email list, a seperate channel.

Trying to be secure from all attackers is generally not possible without severe access restrictions and hardware such as HSMs. Even then there are nations states with huge budgets and in the end [Rubber-hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis).

Answer (score 0):

If I get correctly your situation, your fear is that someone could:

1. have access to the database
2. realize the basics of your "anti-tamper" schema
3. realize it is based on a plain MD5 hash
4. forge a modified object
5. substitute the original object with the forged one and the original hash with the MD5 of the forged object

The most frightening thing in this scenario is that the attacker just needed access to a single system, the database, to deceive the anti-tampering mechanism.

A first attempt to make it less easy, could be to add a "secret key" in the application system too: in your code, you could add a fixed prefix (salt) to the string to be hashed, so the attacker would need both the access to the database and this "secret" information to tamper the data.

However, as @zaph clearly underline, this is just as robust as it is possible to keep it secret to the attacker (that has been already been able to access your database).

To make it worse, this "salt" is not necessary just in the application that writes the data, but it should also be shared with the application reading the data, as you suggest that

> the program storing the data may not be the same as the program reading the data.

If we want to further complicate the scheme, we could use a "public key" system: the MD5 would be crypted before storing it with the "writing application" private key, so the "reading application" can read it and verify the message object without being able to forge a new hash.

...but if we get into this, seriously, you'd better have security advices from someone else than a random guy (me) in StackOverflow :-)

Comment: Point well made. As a 'good programmer' I take my advice like my hashes, with a grain of salt.

Comment: Good pun! However I just wanted to stress that I'm not qualified as a security expert.. I still hope to read some other qualified answers to your question.